# Ansible playbook to fetch patch from specific repos

Tags: yum, repository, ansible, cloud

I have a Instance running in cloud environment that has multiple repos enabled on it, How can I perform patching  only specific repos, The yum should not update any package from repos which are non-os one.

example - yum repolist
repo1 - Source OS providers
repo2 - Source OS Providers
repo3 - Source Third party application

playbook :

```
yum:
 name: *
 state: latest
```

How to restrict yum to not to update any package from third party repos.

- I do not want to move the third party repos config file nor want to disable them.

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to tell `yum` all the packages not to update.
Here's an example to exclude updates for all git, bash, php packages.

```
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:
  - name: Exclude some packages from upgrade in Ansible.
    yum:
      name: "*"
      state: latest
      exclude: 
        - git*
        - bash*
        - php*
```

Imho disable and enable the repos per task you want to update your inventory with, would be less work than writing down all packages of repositories to an exclude list.

For reference check `enabled` and `exclude` in the docs.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/yum_repository_module.html

Comment: thanks for reply but I do not want exclude specific package, I want to exclude all package which come from third party repos provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is a unusual task which yum doesn't support.

Either create your own local repository see [man page reposync](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reposync.1.html)
and run `yum update` on them,

or run `yum check-update`
then `yum list available`
The third column of the result is the repo, `grep` for it and install only the packages you want.

```
Available Packages
2048-cli.x86_64                0.9.1-1.el6      epel
```

Fyi.: move the third party repos config file is different from disabling a repo.
Disabling just sets `enabled=0` in a repo file and will still show up with `yum repolist disabled`.  Disable, update, enable is the easiest and usual way with the same result you want.